# MODX Speed up site suggestions Revolution 2.3.1

Tags: optimization, modx, modx-revolution

I have just set up my first site in MODX Revolution 2.3.1 [www.bountifulbotanicals.com](http://bountifulbotanicals.com) and it appears to be very very slow. The loading time is over 7s with the browser's cache cleared. I've used approx. 35 TV's, there are no snippets and the site only has one page.

Any suggestions how to bring the site's loading time down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire up the chrome inspector & take a look at the network and timeline, your site is actually loading in under a second. It's that 10 megabytes of images that are taking all the time to load. I grabbed and optimized a couple of the thumbs & got them down to about a third of the size without any real effort. So do that for starters [if you are using phpthumbof look at the docs for compression options] see if you can enable server side compression for images. If all that fails you will have to find a solution to load the thumbs on demand [as someone scrolls to a section] using jquery. [sorry, I don't know of one offhand, but I'm sure someone will suggest one]

Comment: thanks. I've reduced the size of thumbs, it did help a bit. I've also reduced the number of TVs which was apparently causing the slow down too...

Comment: one of the tricks with TVs if you are retrieving them with something like getResources is to not process them ~ specifically images. that will save a few ticks as well